# Draw from Truncated Normal

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to draw from the truncated normal distribution using truncnorm.rvs. The truncation is not standard: I am trying to draw from a `N(x_i^T*beta, 1/lambda_i)` truncated at the right by zero.
I used the following code:

```
    b0 = np.dot(1/lambd[np.where(y ==0)],(0-meanZ[np.where(y ==0)]))
    Z[np.where(y ==0)] = truncnorm.rvs(a = -np.inf, b = 0, loc = meanZ[np.where(y ==0)], scale = 1/lambd[np.where(y ==0)])
```

My two problems are: 
- I still get positive values for the Z's
- I also get -np.inf values that mess with the rest of my code
For example, with `b0= -2445.6`,

```
loc = [ -4.262042 -11.300968  -5.482057  -5.660079  -5.586314   3.926029
-3.998386  -7.042979  -9.910377  -1.485213  -5.607546  -3.452188
-3.808936  -3.890414  -6.015614  -4.298134  -6.732967  -7.896627
-10.468604]
```

and,

```
scale = [1.416786e+01 9.202257e+01 2.927436e+00 1.769420e+01 2.318473e+00
 1.053422e+03 8.480848e-01 1.023893e+00 1.837827e+00 1.849986e+01 
6.647380e+00 4.088136e+01 1.860682e+00 1.490134e+01 2.811685e+00 
3.485057e+00 1.108821e+00 1.344376e+01 1.463855e+00]
```

Answer (score 1):

The shape, as set by the parameters `a` and `b`, is defined with respect to the *standard* normal distribution (mean 0, variance 1).

You want to restrict the distribution `N(mu, sigma**2)` to negative values; that is, you want `N(mu, sigma**2)` < 0.  Use the properties of the normal distribution to write that as:

```
N(mu, sigma**2) = mu + sigma * N(0, 1) < 0
```

or

```
N(0, 1) < -mu/sigma
```

So you must set `b` to `-mu/sigma`.

Here's a short script to demonstrate:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import truncnorm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


mu = -2.0
sigma = 3.5

size = 25000

x = truncnorm.rvs(a=-np.inf, b=-mu/sigma, loc=mu, scale=sigma, size=size)

plt.hist(x, bins=100, density=True, alpha=0.6)
xx = np.linspace(x.min(), 0, 400)
yy = truncnorm.pdf(xx, a=-np.inf, b=-mu/sigma, loc=mu, scale=sigma)
plt.plot(xx, yy, 'k--', linewidth=1)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

The script generates this plot:

[image: plot]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it solved my first issue! I still get inf values however, would you know how to avoid this?

Comment: I don't understand how you get inf.  Can you add a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to the question that produces inf?

Comment: For example, with :   np.random.seed(12345) and Z = truncnorm.rvs(a = 31.399904/0.822358, b = np.inf, loc = 31.399904, scale = 0.822358), I get Z = inf